# How/when to use XmlPullParser.require() method

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

Android newbie disclaimer: I'm an Android newbie, please go easy on me.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand [Android's Parsing XML Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) example, specifically their usage of parser.require() - under the heading "Read the Feed".

Yes, I've read [the documentation for XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). I must be an idiot, because I can't make sense of it.

I've also dug around these SO forums and wasn't successful in finding an answer I could personally parse :-)

Okay, so it throws an exception if the parameters passed in are not met. How does that help me when it appears to be applied only to a single element?

How am I supposed to know which parameters to pass in to the method?

Is it always necessary? Or just sometimes? Why?

Should I be using this method whenever I parse XML? Where? Why?

Their example seems to be addressing the "feed" tag at the beginning of the XML feed, but they don't seem to address the "title" tag immediately following. Why would they assert the "feed" tag but not the following "title" tag?

Oh my god I'm so confused.

My frustration with developing for Android is growing beyond measure, and this one little issue is about to send me over the edge. If anyone could please explain in simple terms to me why use the .require() method, and when it's appropriate, I would be forever grateful.

I have no sample code of my own to post here since all I'm doing is reading and trying to understand the example code.

Thanks in advance to all that try to help me with this.

Comment: I know you've marked this as answered, but I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about the cursor being moved. Also, taking a look at `KXmlParser`'s implementation of `require()`, there is only a simple `if` statement.. again, nothing about moving the cursor. What confuses me in Android's example is that the `require(START_TAG)` calls in `readTitle()`, `readLink()` etc seem to be redundant because those methods are only called when the appropriate tag is found in `readFeed()`.

Comment: Interestingly, I removed the `require()` calls in `readTitle()`, `readLink` and the XML file was parsed just fine.. So, my first impression is that `require()` is unnecessary in cases where you can guarantee the structure of the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after posting this question I think I figured out how .require() works. Take the following code snippet from developers.android.com:

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        continue;
    }
    String name = parser.getName();
    // Starts by looking for the entry tag
    if (name.equals("entry")) {
        entries.add(readEntry(parser));
    } else {
        skip(parser);
    }
}
```

...what I'm taking away from this is that by using .require() we're setting our cursor to the START_TAG of the "feed" element - the top level element - and then we can drop into a loop until we finally hit the END_TAG *of the feed element we originally queued up to!*

So, .require() not only verifies the entry point for an xml element, but it also informs the parser of which element you're entering so you can iterate through it until you hit the closing tag for that specific element.

Easier to understand than I gave credit for - sorry for the initial whiny post!

Comment: Hey buddy. You figured out the answers to all your questions now? I'm working on an app that involves parsing XML and that brought me here.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I forgot to mark my own answer as correct. Have a quick look, hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Hi Sashu. I am having quite an issue with XMLPullParser. When you use parser.require(""), does every eventType correspond directly to the tag you set in the require method?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Android's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), the `parser.require()` method uses this signature:

```
require(int type, String namespace, String name)
```

...which queues the parser to the named element (`name`), in the declared namespace (`namespace`), at the event type you specify (`type`). Here's a simple XML fragment to help you visualize:

```
<foo>Hello World!</foo>
```

`parser.require( XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "foo" )` will initially queue your cursor to the foo element's start tag: `<foo>`

`parser.require( XmlPullParser.TEXT, ns, "foo" )` will initially queue your cursor to the text within the foo element: `"Hello World!"`

`parser.require( XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "foo" )` will initially queue your cursor to the foo element's end tag: `</foo>`

From wherever you place your cursor in the document with `parser.require()`, you can then iterate through as much of the document with `parser.next()` as you care to.

As you iterate, you can check each "event" to figure out what type it is: `START_TAG`, `TEXT`, `END_TAG`, or `END_DOCUMENT`. Your logic can then handle each event and its value based on your needs.